# Finding bases for the kernel and image of $M= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-s&2+s&-1\\-s&s&1\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a Matrix
$$M= \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-s&2+s&-1\\-s&s&1\end{bmatrix}$$

and a linear transformation $$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad x \mapsto Mx$$

and I'm supposed to find the bases of the kernel and image.

I know that I just need to find the null space and column space of the matrix. But those $s$ in the matrix are really confusing me right now. Can somebody point me in the right direction.

Also I need to find the *s* for which this linear transformation is injective, surjective, and bijective. I believe that it is injective if the kernel is zero, but how do I show that it is surjective?

Comment: You just need to reduce the matrix so that you see the null-space. You will have to discriminate values of $s$. For instance, if I see it correctly, whenever $s\neq 1/3$ and $s\neq -1$ then the null-space is simply $Ker f ) \{(0,0,0)\}$, i.e. $f$ is one-to-one or also called a monomorphism. Now if $s=-1/3$ you can study the concrete example for which you may not have a problem, by parametrying for instance $z=\lambda$ and write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ or maybe you need to parametrize $z=\lambda$ and $y=\mu$ and get $x$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ and so on. Finally $s=-1$.

Comment: For your second question: recall the dimension theorem, which asserts that for a linear $T:V \rightarrow U$, $\text{dim}(V)=\text{dim}(\text{Range})+\text{dim} (\text{Kernel})$. So in your case every injective map is surjective, and conversely, hence even bijective.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense